# Roslyn SemanticModel symbol resolution not working reliably

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm writing a program that needs to analyze C# code and figure out, for each method invocation, exactly what method of what class is being called. The appropriate tools for this job would seem to be Roslyn, CSharpSyntaxTree and SemanticModel, but they are not working reliably. When I run it on real code, it finds the correct symbol in a few cases, a list of candidates including the correct symbol in a few more, but in most cases, completely fails.

For a reproducible test case, here is a distilled version of the analysis code:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] _) {
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation")
                              .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication))
                              .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                                             MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Console).Assembly.Location),
                                             MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Environment).Assembly.Location),
                                             MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(
                                                 Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location), "System.Runtime.dll")));

        var file = "Class1.cs";
        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(File.ReadAllText(file), CSharpParseOptions.Default, file);
        if (tree.GetDiagnostics().Any()) {
            foreach (var diagnostic in tree.GetDiagnostics())
                Console.Error.WriteLine(diagnostic);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        compilation = compilation.AddSyntaxTrees(tree);

        var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
        var root = tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot();
        new Walker(model).Visit(root);
    }
}

class Walker: CSharpSyntaxWalker {
    public Walker(SemanticModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public override void VisitInvocationExpression(InvocationExpressionSyntax node) {
        base.VisitInvocationExpression(node);

        var symbolInfo = model.GetSymbolInfo(node);
        Console.WriteLine(node);
        Console.WriteLine(symbolInfo.Symbol);
        Console.WriteLine(symbolInfo.CandidateSymbols.ToArray());
    }

    readonly SemanticModel model;
}
```

I run it on this code:

```
class Class1 {
    void Method1() {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Environment.Exit(0)

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISymbol[]
```

So for a static call to the standard library, that should be easy to resolve, it finds no candidate symbols.

What am I missing?

Comment: A good debugging trick is to call GetDiagnostics() on the semantic model or compilation to see if you have compile errors. Your setup for grabbing references that way is highly suspect depending on which target framework you're trying to run on; consider referencing the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzer.Testing NuGet package which will give you a ReferenceAssemblies type that has the list for various target frameworks.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Right, as you can see, my code does check the diagnostics.

Comment: You want to check diagnostics from the compilation or semantic model though: the tree diagnostics will only tell you about parse errors, and not semantic errors which are going to be your problem with symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **InvocationExpressionSyntax**. In your example there is no method invocation. I've used this example:

```
    using System;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class MyClass
        {
            void Method(string input)
            {
                var x = new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            void MethodB(string input)
            {
                Method("TestMe");
            }

            void MethodC(string input)
            {
                MethodB("TestYou");
            }
        }
    }
```

and my code is the following:

```
    using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
    using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
    using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] _)
        {

            var file = "Class1.cs";
            var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(File.ReadAllText(file), CSharpParseOptions.Default, file);
            if (tree.GetDiagnostics().Any())
            {
                foreach (var diagnostic in tree.GetDiagnostics())
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(diagnostic);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(
                                                     Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location), "System.Runtime.dll"));
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation", new[] { tree }, new[] { mscorlib });
            var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

            var root = tree.GetRoot();
            var objectCreationExpression = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().ToList();        
            var lstNodes = objectCreationExpression;
            foreach (var item in lstNodes)
            {
                new Walker(semanticModel).Visit(item);
            }

        }
    }

    class Walker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
    {
        public Walker(SemanticModel model)
        {
            this.model = model;
        }

        public override void VisitInvocationExpression(InvocationExpressionSyntax node)
        {
            base.VisitInvocationExpression(node);

            var symbolInfo = model.GetSymbolInfo(node);
            Console.WriteLine(node);
            Console.WriteLine(symbolInfo.Symbol);
            Console.WriteLine(symbolInfo.CandidateSymbols.ToArray());
        }

        readonly SemanticModel model;
    }
```

Comment: My code does find an `InvocationExpressionSyntax`, namely the `Environment.Exit(0)`, as reported in the output.

Comment: @rwallace So what do u expect else? The candidate symbols? - The list is populated when there are problems  - From the doc: If the expression did not successfully resolve to a symbol, but there were one or more symbols that may have been considered but discarded, this property returns those symbols. The reason that the symbols did not successfully resolve to a symbol are available in the CandidateReason property. For example, if the symbol was inaccessible, ambiguous, or used in the wrong context.

Comment: Right, I would have been unsurprised by resolution failure 'if the symbol was inaccessible, ambiguous, or used in the wrong context', but in this case it was none of these. Good call pointing out CandidateReason. Tried printing that out as well, and it outputs None.